# #arraymap not include delimiter in output

Tags: mediawiki

Many, many times, I have wanted to create a template that takes a list of values, and displays them in a table, each on their own line. I've tried hiding the comma in a span, but that breaks the table.

```
<span style="display:none;">{{#arraymap: {{{programmers|}}}|,|x|</span><!--
-->{{!}} Programmer: {{!!}} x
{{!-}}<span style="display:none;">}}</span>
```

Is there a method of hiding the delimiter and still getting a table, or perhaps, is there a separate way to do this altogether?

If you want a full simplified testcase, I have the following input:

```
{{authors|programmers=Ryan Scheel, Ryan Dean}}
```

and I want the following output:

```
{| class="wikitable"
|-
! colspan="2" style="text-align:center;" ! Authors
|-
| Programmer: || Ryan Scheel
|-
| Programmer: || Ryan Dean
|}
```

or in template form:

```
{{{!}} class="wikitable"
{{!-}}
! colspan="2" style="text-align:center;" ! Authors
{{!-}}
{{!}} Programmer: {{!!}} Ryan Scheel
{{!-}}
{{!}} Programmer: {{!!}} Ryan Dean
{{!}}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved your problem by passing an empty 5th argument to the function<sup>[1]</sup>. This argument defines what to replace the delimiter with.

```
{{#arraymap: Ryan Scheel, Ryan Dean|,|x|<nowiki />
{{!-}}
{{!}} Programmer: {{!!}} x
|<!-- empty 5th parameter -->}}
```

expanded result will be as following:

```
{|
<nowiki />
|-
| Programmer: || Ryan Scheel<nowiki />
|-
| Programmer: || Ryan Dean
|}
```

I slightly modified your example for my own convenience during my tests, feel free to adjust it to your taste. I put the `|-` (HTML <tr>) before the `|` (HTML <td>) because it is more logical.

More important, as you may already know, arguments of parser functions are trimed<sup>[2]</sup>. The problem is that wiki tables markup (`{|`, `|-`, etc.) should be at the beginning of the lines of the source, otherwise it is not interpreted<sup>[3]</sup>. So, in order to insert a linebreak, in this example before the `|-`'s, I used the pretty `<nowiki />` trick ;-)

As a side note, your line `! colspan="2" (...) ! Authors` has a mistake, the `!` before "Authors" has to be a `|` instead.

[1] documentation at http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_Forms/Semantic_Forms_and_templates

[2] contrary to unnamed parameters of templates!

[3] The only exception, as far as I know, is that you can put spaces and HTML comments before.

Comment: The <nowiki /> trick I did not know of. That explains why I see them in Wikipedia templates. I did not know [2], but [3] I did.

After asking this question, I did learn of the fifth parameter, but I did not think of making it empty.

Many thanks.